# How to limit a Coded UI Test control search

Tags: c#, user-interface, msdn, coded-ui-tests, ui-testing

Using MS Coded UI, is there a way to specify that a search for a control must begin at a specific parent?

I'm performing a search for a control, and I want to perform different actions based on the success or failure of that search.  Unfortunately, the search is always successful (regardless of the existence of the control at question) because of another control (with an entirely different parent) that has an identical automation id (the application is quite large, and consequently this happens frequently).

I'm guessing that the search starts at the specified parent and looks for the desired control.  When it is not found, I believe the search starts again from the root, and this time the identically named control is found (though it is not the one I'm interested in and it is part of a different subtree).

My question is whether or not you can limit the search for a control to a particular subtree.  For example, consider the case where the primary view, Main, has two subviews View1 and View2.  Each  subview contains a control with an auto ID of "coolControl."

Is there a way to limit the UI search so that a search will only be successful if it is found under a particular parent (say View1)? Upon failure, can I prevent the search from restarting at the root?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you can do that,

Are you familiar with Search Properties and Filter Properties?

If not what I recommend you do is the following.

1. Go to **UIMap.uitest** file
2. Right Click on your action and select **properties**

In Search Properties you can add a new property such as TagName or TagInstance or remove a property or a Filter Property that is causing you problems.

*If that dosen't work or if you have already tried that your going to need to manually write the search code which is tricky.*

Answer (score 1):

The common answer is to add more details to the **SearchProperties** or **FilterProperties**.

For a more complex answer, look in the methods recorded by Coded UI. The methods in UI Map class have lines such as (where this line was from clicking a Windows 7 Start button):

```
WinButton uIStartButton = this.UIStartWindow.UIStartButton;
```

More generally the lines are like

```
SomeUiControl uISomeControl = this.UIParent.UIChild.UIGrandChild;
```

Then the code just uses the control, eg `Mouse.Click(uIStartButton, new Point(29, 27));` on the above start button.

You can add your own methods to the `uimap.cs` file, but not to the `uimap.designer.cs` file as it is regenerated whenever the UI Map changes. As it contributes to the UI Map (using `partial class`s) your code can select any top level control and start your search from there.

I suggest reading the generated code carefully to see how the Coded UI generated code uses the classes, types and instances in the UI Map. Note also that using a property (eg using the value of `UIParent` in the expression `this.UIParent.UIChild`) causes the `Find` method to be called and that makes use of the SearchProperties and FilterProperties of that item.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The testing we're doing is building on top of the Coded UI Test framework and we're hand-coding everything.  I'm accessing the controls using the syntax you mentioned, the trouble is that I need more control over the actual search; I want to prevent the search from restarting upon failure.  I think you're right in that I need to explore the search properties more rigorously.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Each Class that inherits from UITestControl has a constructor that accepts another UITestControl - That UITestControl becomes the parent(Or Ancestor farther up) of the control you're searching for, effectively limiting the search in the way you want. The default constructor(The parameterless one) uses the desktop as the ancestor for the search. For example:

```
WinButton UIButtonStartButton = new WinButton();
```

Creates a button to add search properties to that could be in any window descending from the desktop.

```
WinButton UIButtonStartButton = new WinButton(MyApplicationWindow);
```

Creates a button to add search properties to that is only in the specified window.

```
WinButton UIButtonStartButton = new WinButton(View1);
```

Creates a button to add search properties to that is only in the specified view.

Any UITestControl can be passed in as the parent, though of course only certain UITestControls will have descendents.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but there is a way to find the exact control. You can find a control under its parent with the exact hierarchy

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.MatchExactHierarchy = true;
```

use the above line in Test initialization,so if you set the MatchExactHierarchy to true then it only finds the control under the same parent you are mentioning.

There would be some cache issue which might again find you wrong control.

If you want to know more about codedUI, refer [my blog](http://codeduiadda.blogspot.in/2014/11/search-configurations-for-control-in.html)